# "Petit à petit" vs "peu à peu" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, locutions

To translate *little by little*, is there any difference between these two choices? Not a super important thing, exactly, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both express the same thing, but there is a little bit difference between them:

We use ***petit à petit*** to describe a process/action which steps are evolving slowly but still they are clear and distinguishable ones:

- ***Petit à petit***, l'oiseau fait son nid: This is a proverd and it means: little by little, the bird constructs its nest
- *J'ai construit ma maison **petit à petit***: I have  built my house little by little: The process of building, even if it is slow, involves clear and distinguisable steps.

We use ***peu à peu*** to describe a process/action which steps are evolving slowly but this process is not clear in that its steps are not distinguishable:

- *Le climat se réchauffe **peu à peu**:* the climate is warming little by little.